# Determinant with factorials

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $D_n$ be the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\frac1{(n+1)!}&\cdots&\cdots&\frac1{1!}\\
\vdots&&&\vdots\\
\vdots&&&\vdots\\
\frac1{(2n+1)!}&\cdots&\cdots&\frac1{(n+1)!}
\end{vmatrix}$$
Can one determine the value or at least an equivalent of $D_n$ when $n\to+\infty$?
Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Try to use the Leibniz formula for determinants to determine the limit of $\mathrm{det}(D_n)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @cerocius. Did you try what you say? It looks awful.

Comment: I think @cerocius solves the problem $\det (D_n) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_{n+1} } \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{(n + 1 + \sigma(i) - \sigma(j))!}$ $\leq$ $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)! n! ...1!} \leq \frac{1}{n!}$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple explicit expression for this determinant. But the proof is not that simple. Here are the ideas:

I rewrite it has a Hankel determinant of order $n$, it just change up to a sign $(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$ and a shift.

First consider the determinant:

$$D_n(x)=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac1{1!}x&\cdots&\cdots&\frac1{n!}x^n\\
\vdots&&&\vdots\\
\vdots&&&\vdots\\
\frac1{n!}x^n&\cdots&\cdots&\frac1{(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1}
\end{vmatrix}.
$$

Then derive it $n^2$ times, it yields with some multiplicity, the triangular determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
0 & \dots &  & 0 & 1\\
\vdots & & & 1 & x\\
\vdots &  &  &  & \vdots\\
0 & 1 & \dots &  & \frac1{(n-2)!}x^{n-2}\\
1  & x & \dots & \frac1{(n-2)!}x^{n-2} & \frac1{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}\\ 
\end{vmatrix}=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}.
$$

The multiplicity is the multidimensionnal ballot number from $(0,1,\dots,n-1)$ to $(n,n+1,\dots,2n-1)$:
$$\frac{(n^2)!(n!!)^2}{(2n)!!}$$
where $n!!=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(k!)$. (Ref. in Nathanson, Additive Combinatorics)

So we deduce that
$$D_n(x)=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\frac{(n^2)!(n!!)^2}{(2n)!!}\frac1{(n^2)!}x^{n^2}=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\frac{(n!!)^2}{(2n)!!}x^{n^2},$$

and finally $$D_n=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\frac{(n!!)^2}{(2n)!!}=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{i!}{(n+i)!},$$
and therefore:
$$|D_n|\leq \frac1{(n!)^n}$$

I skipped some details and there may be simpler proofs, but you got the expression that I checked for $n=2,3$.

Comment: Can you please explain, what do you mean by "Then derive it $n^2$ times".

Comment: can someone please explain this step?